# Parsing Image in Java with different actions for different pixel colours

Tags: java, image, pixel, javax.imageio

I want to colour every black pixel in my image with the color the previous pixel had. And if there are 2 or more consecutive black pixels, the colour of the last non-black pixel is taken. I figured out how to iterate through pixels but the pixels won't change their colour. I think I miss the "save changes" line.

Here the code:

```
public static void iteratePixels() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\blackDots.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    int lastNotBlack = -1;
    int actualColour = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getHeight(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getWidth(); y++) {

            int black = -16777216;

            try {
                actualColour = image.getRGB(x, y);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
            if(image.getRGB(x, y)==black){
                image.setRGB(x, y, lastNotBlack);

                System.out.println("black pixel at: " +x +" "+y);
            }
            if (actualColour != black){
                lastNotBlack= actualColour;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So how do I appy the changes ? Or is there another mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the pixels only in the in-memory image, but you need to write those pixels back to a file:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\blackDots_modified.png"));
```

(to be called after all pixels have been modified)

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Comment: thanks, now a new image is being created but it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/bqnQoHK.png The source file was a plain white image with some black dots on it. And why are the last pixelrows ignored? When I take out the try-catch part I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!

Comment: Then something with your algorithm must be wrong. I only provided the line for saving the image after you manipulated the pixels, which was the original question asked.

Comment: X is usually the width, y the height. In your for-loops, you have it exactly the other way round which might explain the given Exception

Comment: ah yeah that was the mistake. Thanks!